# return specific fields for instagram Api

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Use the following request to get the recent media of a user.

```
$url_posts = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/'.$Userid.'/media/recent?client_id='.$admin_userid.'&count='.$numposts;
```

know whant to only restrict the fields that goes fetch is it possible? if so how?

Comment: Definitely interested in this too. A page of data that has a lot of comments gets incredibly bloated.